# Kendo Grid Syntax - Adding Font-Awesome Icon Programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, kendo-ui

Desired behavior: Kendo grid has column for "isActive?" which is populated by a green fas-fa-clock icon if isActive == true and by grey far-fa-clock if false. The icon has an onClick to toggle between t/f.

Current behavior: Grid exists and populates the field with the word true or false.

code:

component.html

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridView" [sortable]="{ allowUnsort: true, mode: 'single' }" [sort]="sort"
                (sortChange)="sortChange($event)" [height]="auto">
      <kendo-grid-column field="someItems" title="items" width=7>
      </kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-column field="isActive" title="A?" width="4" spriteCssClass="fa fa-flag-checkered">
      </kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-column field="moreItems" title="items" width="4">
      </kendo-grid-column>
    </kendo-grid>
```

The spriteCssClass does nothing. I'm not sure how to get this to do this correctly.

It's also all created in html - a convention which none of the stuff I've read has seemed to support.

Resources:

https://fontawesome.com/icons/clock?style=solid

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/navigation/menu/how-to/using-fontawesome-icons

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/hybrid/styles/icons

https://www.telerik.com/forums/adding-images-to-a-column-in-kendo-grid

App is Angular/ts

Anybody know the correct syntax for this?

Comment: Did you look at column cell templates: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/templates/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All linked Kendo UI resources are for Kendo UI for jQuery while the question seems to be about Kendo UI for Angular?

As already suggested, check out the [cell templates example](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/templates/#toc-cell-template), you will also need to load the FontAwesome CSS:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="Discontinued">
          <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
            <i class="fa fa-flag-checkered" [style.color]="dataItem.Discontinued ? 'grey': 'green'" aria-hidden="true" (click)="dataItem.Discontinued = !dataItem.Discontinued"></i>
          </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
```

[EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uvvq5c?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. The live example link is very useful for tinkering and finding the right syntax.